# Correct way of thinking about primitive assignment

Tags: java, primitive

In this example,

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
x = 4;
```

y will remain 5 because x is just being reassigned and it is not manipulating the object it used to refer to in anyway. My question is, is what I just said a correct way of thinking about it? Or is there a duplication of the memory stored in 'x' and that duplication is put in 'y'.

Comment: the data stored in x is copied to y

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primitives, unlike objects, are stored directly inside the variable. That is, a variable of primitive type is not storing a reference to a primitive, it stores the primitive's value directly.

When one primitive variable is assigned to another primitive variable, it copies the value.

When you do

`int x = 5;
int y = x;
x = 4;`

`x` sets the value inside of it to 4, and `y` still has the value 5 because its value is separate.

The only way for one variable to be changed by a change to another variable, is if both variables are references to a 'mutable' object, and the object is mutated - since they both are looking at the same object, rather than their own copies, they both observe the same change. (Note for example that strings, being immutable, will never 'suddenly change', but arrays and collections can)

Comment: you say that "x" stores the primitives value directly, but in reality isn't "x" also just a type of reference? "x" can't really store anything, it's just a letter. It must refer to the space in memory, like references to object types, the only difference is reassignments will make changes within the memory it refers instead of changing  which memory space it refers to. Am I right?

Comment: Don't forget that `x` is not required to be allocated space in memory - it could exist only on a register, or be optimized out of existence, by the compilation process. Also, there are no meta-variables in Java - that is, you can't have a variable that you can say 'make this point to the variable `x` - not what `x` points to, `x` itself', so the level of variable is the lowest level of non-redirection you can have. You are kind of right but not in a way you can utilize as a Java programmer.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 separate location for the `x` and `y`. `x` and `y` here are primitives not objects.

When you do

```
int y = x;
```

A separate memory for int variable `y` is created and the value of `x` i.e `5` is copied into that location.

after this, if you reassign any other value to the variable `x` by doing :

```
x = 4;
```

, it does not reflect in the value of `y`.

Even if you use Wrapper class `Integer` it will behave in the similar fashion, since these are immutable classes. for example:

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
Integer Y = x; //now both `x` and `y` point to the same `integer` object with the value 5.
x= new Integer(4); // now since `x` is pointing to a different object than `y`, both `x` and `y` remain independent(i.e change in one does not reflect in another).
```

Answer (score 1):

primitive variables actually hold the value (not the reference). So at any point of time you create a primitive variable, a memory block (of that primitive type) gets reserved for a value, no matter you have assigned a value for that or not.

> (in any low level language you can think of a variable as a register)